# Airflow Clean Up Pods

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

Currently we have a CronJob to clean pods deployed by airflow.
Cleanup cron job in airflow is defined as follows
[image]

This Cleans all completed pods (Successful pod and Pods that are marked as Error).

I have a requirement where in CleanUp Pods CronJob shouldn't clean Pods that are marked as **ERROR**.
I checked Airflow Docs but couldn't get anything. Any other way in which i can achieve this

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 airflow environments variables that might help.

AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS - If True, all worker pods will be deleted upon termination

AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS_ON_FAILURE - If False (and delete_worker_pods is True), failed worker pods will not be deleted so users can investigate them. This only prevents removal of worker pods where the worker itself failed, not when the task it ran failed

for more details see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#delete-worker-pods-on-failure)

Comment: How can we prevent Deletion of Task Pods which are in Failed state, Currently We are using following Command "kubernetes cleanup-pods --namespace=pipelines-ns" This Cleans up all pods irrespective of the state of the pod.